# Появление div по клику

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при клике по кнопке появлялся текст div'a, а изначально был показан текст первого div'a?

HTML

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item">First item</a>
                <a class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
                <a class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <div class="section">Some text</div>
            <div class="section">And more text</div>
            <div class="section">Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery Core -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
    .list-group-item {
       margin: 10px;
       position: relative;
       display: block;
       cursor: pointer;
    }

    .section {
       display: none;
    }
```

jQuery

```
   $(".list-group-item").on("click", function(){
var idx = $(this).index();

$(".section").hide();
$(".section").eq(idx).toggle(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".section").eq(idx).toggle();` я бы заменил для пущей уверенности `$(".section").eq(idx).show();` ну и есть замечательный класс у bootstrap `hide`

```
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
        <div class="section">Some text</div>
        <div class="section hide">And more text</div>
        <div class="section hide">Lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
```

Стиль `.section` удалите он не нужен, а jQuery перепишите

```
$(".list-group-item").on("click", function(){
   var idx = $(this).index();

   $(".section").addClass('hide');
   $(".section").eq(idx).removeClass('hide'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз мы говорим о bootstrap, может лучше использовать collapse, по смыслу вроде подходит, вот: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте пример по возможности

Comment: Collapse тут, к сожалению, не подходит, ибо вся информация будет выпадать в колонке справа.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, естественно можно задать определенному a открытие

```js
$(".list-group-item").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".dn").toggle();
});
```

```css
 .dn{
  display: none;
 }

 .list-group-item {
   margin: 10px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="list-group">
       <a class="list-group-item">First item</a>
       <a class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
       <a class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8 dn">
     <div class="section">Some text</div>
     <div class="section">And more text</div>
     <div class="section">Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Зачем создавать классы которые есть в `bootstrap`?

Comment: Ваш класс `.dn` так же бессмыслен так как есть у `botstrap` класс `.hide`

Comment: Я скопировал код указанный выше. Внес только изменения. Вопрос чистки не стоял. Этот код пример как все работает, не думаю что резонно вставлять в пример код бутстрапа

Comment: Так Ваш пример вообще и не рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Bootstrap Tabs

Пример

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">First item</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Second item</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Third item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h3>Title 1</h3>
                    <p>Some content.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Title 2</h3>
                    <p>Some content.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Title 3</h3>
                    <p>Some content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```